# Login an Download via cURL

Tags: php, login, curl

I have a little Problem with a new Site.

On https://wsv.mitcom.online i want to login via cURL and download some CSV files.

I already tried it with

curl --user User:XXXX 'https://wsv.mitcom.online/index.html'

curl --data "emailLogin=User&passwort0=XXXX$&login=true" https://wsv.mitcom.online

and many other....

Have anyone an idea or a solution?

Tank you

Comment: “I have a little Problem” ; What problem? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?

Comment: Wild guesses - Did you need to specify a "-c" option for a cookie jar and/or fix CA/ignore CA issues as per https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Comment: Hi the last an best try is
curl --cookie-jar cookies1.txt --form passwort0=XXXX --form user=NAPOsync https://wsv.mitcom.online/login.aspx?login=true

But then i only became a meassage <h2>Object moved to <a href="/startseite.aspx">here</a>.</h2>

Does anybody have an idea?
Mayby i can mail you the password?